Adapting a frequency divider circuit for higher frequencies
I'm trying to build a frequency divider using discrete components (as a part of a hobby/learning project). The final goal is dividing an input signal of 32.768kHz to an output of 1Hz, by dividing the input by 2, 15 times. So I'm now trying to build one div-by-2 stage.
As a basis for this, I'm trying to use a circuit found on this website: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/bistable.html :

And while I understand (I believe) the principle of its operation (how the bistable circuit holds the state, and how the falling edge of the input pulls down the base of the active transistor, causing it to flip the state), I fail to understand, where the exact parts values come from.
The values used on that website seem to be chosen for a low-frequency input. In KiCad/ngspice simulator, I was able to make it principality working (although not without spikes) for an input signal of 1kHz (red - input, blue - output):

However, applying a 32.768kHz input signal, I got this:

Clearly, the multivibrator circuit isn't able to switch so fast, it only reacts every 3-6 falling edge.
How to adapt the circuit to work with an input of such frequency? I tried to change various values, but never achieved a stable operation. I've even built the circuit on a breadboard but the results there were the same (or even worse). Also, I'd rather understand what I'm doing rather than trying random component values in a hope of finding the right combination. I'd thus greatly appreciate more systematic/mathematical help in this analysis.

I haven't even looked very closely, but this is surprisingly slow. Try scaling down every resistor value by a factor of 10, to see whether that changes things

@MarcusMüller indeed, this helped (at least in the simulation)! Thanks, that's already a step in a good direction for me. However, I'd still like to understand why it helps. I previously tried to change values of the resistors (and capacitors too for that matter), but never all of them at once. Is there some relationship between these resistance and switching speed?

Your 1st trace (where Vin has period of 2ms) divides-by-2 OK. These circuits should be able to divide-by-n, where n is an integer...divide-by-3, divide-by-4 etc. But as n becomes large, R-C component values become more critical to achieve a stable lock-in. Your second attempt has too-high n and seems somewhat unstable. Blocking oscillators can divide-by-n, but become squirrelly for n > 5

The C1 has to keep-up to align the actual Q1 collector state during
V2_high time.  (On Q2 side the same of course).
So the time constant of \$C1\cdot R7= \underline{220\text{ µs}}\$ has to be about the same (or less) than V2_high time which is \$\underline{15.3\text{ µs}}\$ at 32.768 kHz.
Decrease the R7&R8 to 150 kOhm and C1&C2 to 220 pF so these caps will align faster.
Edit:
(Answer to comment)
You don’t affect/toggle the collectors with those caps directly but rather affect the bases during pulse low. The charged cap (that is when collector is low) is able to push the base through diode deep negative during pulse low and so turn off the appropriate transistor making the collector high now.
Don’t bother with precise numbers like 63%, it isn’t needed, it would be a challenge where every resistor and cap in circuit would play some role. Rule of thumb is: The best is the RC Tau should be about three time less than pulse high so the caps are completely recharged/aligned (to ~95%) before pulse goes low.

Yes, indeed, that works, thanks! So basically, in my failing case, C1 stays charged for too long, keeping Q1 collector up and preventing the switch from happening? What I'd also like to understand is the meaning of the RC time constant here. From what I read, this is a time needed to dis/charge a capacitor to 63% of the applied voltage - what's so special about this value so that you use it as a threshold in this case?
